Cosine of an operator (a+a.dag()).cosm() in Qutip does not work as it should
As mentioned in the title, the .cosm() method in QuTip fails to give the correct evolution under the Hamiltonian. I am trying to define the Hamiltonian of a non-linear LCJ circuit as follows:
H = Ej * (a.dag() + a).cosm() + ...

I'd like to know if a.cosm() really takes exact cosine of a. If not, what is the correct way of implementing the cosine of an operator in QuTip?
